# Serilog stopped logging

Tags: c#, serilog, .net-core-3.0

I've set-up Serilog file logging as per the instructions:

In my Startup.cs I have the following:

```
...
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, S3DataSettingsProvider settings)
{
    loggerFactory.AddFile(settings.LogFilename);
    ...
    DoStuffThatRequiresLogging(); // runs ok but no log files created
}
```

I have checked that `settings.LogFilename` resolves to the correct filename by adding a breakpoint.

Elsewhere in the code is a class containing the following:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class MyClass
{
    private ILogger<MyClass> _log;
    public ImportRunner(ILogger<MyClass> log)
    {
        _log = log;
        ...
    }

    private void Log(string message)
    {
        _log.LogError($"[{nameof(MyClass)}] {message}");
    }
```

But the logging doesn't work.

If I put a breakpoint on the `_log.LogError` line and explore the `_log` object I can see that there are 4 loggers, and none of them are the file logger I thought I was adding in the startup :(.

This has been working fine in the past, no idea why it has stopped now.

Is there something obviously missing?

Comment: If you breakpoint `Configure`, can you see that that's actually happening? If it is, can you confirm the `ILoggerFactory` instance you get there is correct? There's plenty that can go wrong wiring up dependencies (including the ones you don't even wire up yourself).

Comment: Ok did that; I can see that `Serilog` is added successfully in `_providerRegistrations` but there are 0 `_loggers`. What should I be seeing?

Comment: I think the problem is that the code where I'm logging stuff is called from within `Configure`, so potentially the DI container setup hasn't completed yet. I need to find somewhere else to call that from.

Comment: I'm out of options now. Tried moving code around, playing with DI etc, no help.

Comment: In general, the `UseSerilog()` API enabled by https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore, and _Serilog.Sinks.File_ (included in it), is less hassle